# How to install dependencies on Heroku after deplyment of Node App?

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, nodemon

I have a node app, perfectly running on the localhost. but after deploying it to Heroku it crashes.

Here's the Error Log:

```
2019-11-07T10:58:20.359983+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with 
command `npm start`
2019-11-07T10:58:22.882837+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2019-11-07T10:58:22.866125+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2019-11-07T10:58:22.768738+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2019-11-07T10:58:22.768765+00:00 app[web.1]: > dpapi@1.0.0 start /app
2019-11-07T10:58:22.768768+00:00 app[web.1]: > nodemon --exec babel-node server.js --plugins css-modules-transform --ignore dist/
2019-11-07T10:58:22.768770+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2019-11-07T10:58:22.783839+00:00 app[web.1]: sh: 1: nodemon: not found
2019-11-07T10:58:22.788270+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2019-11-07T10:58:22.788822+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! syscall spawn
2019-11-07T10:58:22.789278+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! file sh
2019-11-07T10:58:22.789688+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno ENOENT
2019-11-07T10:58:22.791368+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! dpapi@1.0.0 start: `nodemon --exec babel-node server.js --plugins css-modules-transform --ignore dist/`
2019-11-07T10:58:22.791637+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
2019-11-07T10:58:22.791917+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2019-11-07T10:58:22.792199+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the dpapi@1.0.0 start script.
2019-11-07T10:58:22.792534+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2019-11-07T10:58:22.802491+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2019-11-07T10:58:22.802775+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2019-11-07T10:58:22.802918+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2019-11-07T10_58_22_793Z-debug.log
```

I am not sure about the cause but it looks like it can't find nodemon, Maybe it's unable to install all the dependencies. as mentioned in the error message;

Here's my Procfile:

```
web: npm start
```

and Here's my package.json

```
{


"name": "dpapi",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon --exec babel-node server.js --plugins css-modules-transform --ignore dist/",
    "dev": "webpack -wd"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.4.4",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "eslint": "^5.16.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.13.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.18.11",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.4.4",
    "@babel/node": "^7.2.2",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.4.4",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-default-from": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.4.4",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.0.0-rc.0",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^3.0.2",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.5",
    "bcrypt": "^3.0.6",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "buffer": "^5.2.1",
    "dropbox": "^4.0.17",
    "ejs": "^2.6.1",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "global": "^4.4.0",
    "imagemagick": "^0.1.3",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "^2.2.1",
    "js-file-download": "^0.4.7",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.5.7",
    "morgan": "^1.9.1",
    "multer": "^1.4.1",
    "node-fetch": "^2.5.0",
    "nodemailer": "^6.2.1",
    "query-string": "^6.5.0",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-redux": "^7.0.3",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.0.0",
    "react-stripe-elements": "^3.0.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.3",
    "socket.io": "^2.2.0",
    "socket.io-client": "^2.2.0",
    "stripe": "^7.4.0",
    "webpack": "^4.30.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: You may need to move `nodemon` from `devDependencies` to `dependencies`.

Comment: You might be able to remove nodemon from the start script altogether and put it in a devstart script instead and just use babel/node to start server.js

Comment: How can I replace nodemon with node in the start script

Answer (score 2):

Heroku deployment fails because it cannot find `nodemon` in your `dependencies`. The easy solution would probably be to move it in there.

The more accurate answer, your current configuration is perfect for development but not for production.
I would advise to first compile your code with webpack (or whatever you currently use), deploy the build code and use the regular `node server.js` as your `npm start` script.
Heroku will take care of restarting your application in case of a failure, you don't need nodemon.

Comment: Do you have a link or reference where I can learn how to compile code?

Comment: @Waeez by looking at your `package.json` it looks like you are using webpack. A simple `npm run webpack` command should compile yoru code (https://webpack.js.org/guides/getting-started/). Please note that you have to deploy your `dist` folder

Comment: I tried that, but my `dist/` is not getting published on heroku with `git push heroku master`. it's not even in my `.gitignore` file